# Safari not working after migration on MacBook Air 2015

Tags: safari, migration

Recently migrated from one MacBook Air to another (both 2015). Safari error message:  "You can't use this version of the application "Safari.App" with this version of OS X.  You have OS X 10.11.6. The application requires OS X 12.3 or later" But there isn't an OS X upgrade available yet.

Comment: When you “migrated,” did you transfer data via Migration Assistant, restore from backup, or something else?  You can try creating a temp user and testing there

Comment: Yes, Exactly that.  Will try the temp user, thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I tried the temp user as suggested and I got the same error message.  Would downloading an earlier version of Safafi help and if so where can I find it (Safari app not available in the App store).

Comment: Personally, I stay away from Safari (and Chrome, but for very different reasons). Try Firefox or Edge before investing a ton of time into this.